# Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Workflow Timer Service documentation

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-services

I've been doing a series of scalability tests on some SharePoint server farms... in my report I've included some notes that in my testing, the Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Workflow Timer Service is started in Central Admin > System Settings > Manage Services on Server. I want to try to be more specific on this service and explain what it does and why I've been using it (I won't go into the details of how my solutions are deployed and how my services are created, but it seems this service seems necessary for things to deploy properly), but I've only found vague blog posts about how app servers should/should not have this service running, etc.

Is anyone aware of some specific documentation regarding this service? This is Sharepoint 2010 by the way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this guy is really good and goes into detail on the documentation, its a big read but should be what your looking for http://www.synergyonline.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=224